# Web Application and website template missing in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Due to some issues I uninstalled Visual Studio, but after reinstalling i found out that website and web application templates were missing.

I repaired the VS from the setup, but still no web templates. I don't know why  this is happening even when web development tools option was checked.

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling VS several times and I really don't know what the problem is.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what can I do to get web templates back?

Comment: Happening to me too.... any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve this problem was by resetting my windows. I tried many ways to solve this problem, but eventually you have to do this the hard way, and that is by installing windows again or resetting it and installing visual studio again.